# Symmetries near the K/K' points in graphene

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, crystals, graphene

I am trying to understand one paper and I have a problem with symmetries.

The authors introduce the 2x2 Bloch Hamiltonian as
$$
\mathcal{H}(\textbf{k}) = \textbf{h}(\textbf{k}) \cdot \sigma,
$$
where $\sigma$ are Pauli matrices and $\textbf{h}(\textbf{k}) = (h_x(\textbf{k}), h_y(\textbf{k}), 0)$.

Then, they claim that the combination of inversion ($\mathcal{P}$) and time-reversal ($\mathcal{T}$) symmetry requires $h_z(\textbf{k})=0$, because
$$
\mathcal{P}: h_z(\textbf{k}) \to -h_z(-\textbf{k}), \\ \mathcal{T}: h_z(\textbf{k})\to h_z(-\textbf{k}).
$$

And I don't understand this and also why this happens only in the $z$--direction.

Also, later they introduce $h_z(\textbf{k})$ to be nonzero and claims that the Dirac point $(\textbf{K'})$ have mass $m'=h_z(\textbf{K}')$. Why?